# Problem with the datepicker format

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have this  `$("#xt1").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy' });` statement for the datepicker  in Jquery with this statement user can enter some value 
for the  date in the  text field where as with this statement  `$("#xt1").datepicker();` user cannot enter  any value in to the Text field . 
How can we format the date and  as well as not allow the user to enter the date

Comment: Did the below answer work for you? :-)

Answer (score 1):

@Derby: Add the `readonly="readonly"` attribute to the `#xt1` `input`, e.g.:

```
<input type="text" name="xt1" id="xt1" readonly="readonly" />
```